# facebook api: how to make a share dialog when we can choose who we share something with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

so, I need a JS / jQuery code that orders Facebook to show a window when I can share a link with the chosen friends. This also must be done with link (not JS).

I found this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog but no luck using it

EDIT: it says "error happened, try again later"

Answer (score 1):

You can use their `sharer.php` endpoint in a simple `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=yoursite.com">Share</a>
```

If you want to open it in a new window, you can use the onclick handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=yoursite.com', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=350,width=550,scrollbars=no,status=no'); return false;">Share</a>
```

Comment: but its not opening a dialog to choose my friends but to share on my wall. I want to send this share as a message to my friends

Comment: There are other options in the dropdown. Click ```On your own Timeline```. If you need finer controls, you will have to build it yourself using the Facebook API at the link you've already posted.